# Task helpers not running Laravel, but cron is running every minute

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron

I have a task I'm trying to run every day. In my Kernel.php I have the following command:

**$schedule->command('emailProgram')->daily()->timezone('US/Central');**

I'm my crontab I have:

*** * * * * php /var/www/html/appname/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1**

So, When I run *php artisan schedule:run*, or run it directly with *php artisan emailProgram* it runs as expected. But, its not running on its own using daily()/dailyAt() or otherwise. Lastly, if I remove daily() from the command in the kernel.php file:

**$schedule->command('emailProgram')->timezone('US/Central');** it's running every minute, so its like there is some disconnect with the Laravel task helpers. This is my first time setting up Cron, and task management with Laravel so maybe I'm overlooking something simple. Any help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is the path to artisan definitely correct in your cron task? This has caught me out before.

Comment: I ended fixing it by adding an output file for the cron results instead of /dev/null. I created a folder inside of storage with an output.txt file inside, and then pointed the cron to that. When I did that it started to work.